# jquery 1.9.1 event handler not firing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

hitting my head against the wall.. google searched and checked previous q's here.. cant find the answer.. using jquery 1.9.1

pretty simple problem... select drop down list, want my func to fire when the drop down list is changed by the user.. problem is . nothing happens.. no errors.. func wont fire

```
$("select.radStatus").change(function() {
    // alert('Value change to ' + $(this).attr('value'));
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax_me.php",
       data: "officeLocName=" + $(this).val(),
       success: function(msg){
           $('#signInResult').html('<img src="img/checkmark.png" />');
        }
    });
});
```

HTML is:

```
<select id="radStatus" name="officeLocName">
<option value="1">choice 1</option>
<option value="2">choice 2</option>
<option value="3">choice 3</option>
</select>
```

i try to sewlect a new option... event doesnt fire... nothing happens.. no errors in firebug

thanks

Update:
thank you it works!

Comment: Should be `$("select#radStatus")`

Comment: @ROYFinley Please add that as an answer so it can upvoted properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is  not the `select` when you are within `$.ajax` and ID prefix needs to be used in selector

There is no point making another DOM search as other answers suggest, just declare the `select` val as variable before the `$.ajax`

```
$("select#radStatus").change(function() {
    var value=$(this).val();
    $.ajax({
       type: "GET",
       url: "ajax_me.php",
       data: "officeLocName=" + value,
       success: function(msg){
           $('#signInResult').html('<img src="img/checkmark.png" />');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: wrap your code in `$(function(){ })`. It is firing before the html it looks for exists

Answer (score 4):

Should be `$("select#radStatus")` . this is for id. the `.` is for class

Comment: i dont know what i am doing wrong.. changed it.. still not working.  i tried putting code on jsfiddle but i cant find a way to get the permalink to post the jsfiddle link here.. frustrating

Comment: @bobafart  did you also change the `this` as stated in charierfl's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change 
`$("select.radStatus")`
to
`$("select#radStatus")`

You have it as a class in the jQuery but as an ID in the html